# Send Multiple SMS to users using Jobs

Tags: laravel, sms, scheduled-tasks, jobs, guzzle

I have around 25K users, I want to send sms for each one of them.

I did the following Job,

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;
use App\User;
use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Post\PostBodyInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

class SendSMS extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
    protected $user;
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

     /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => "example.com"]);

            $messageBody = "Message";
            $data = ["messageBody"=>$messageBody,
                    "msisdn"=>$this->user];

            $client->request('POST', 'SendSMS',[ 'json'=>$data]);

        }
    }
```

And I am dispatching the jobs using JobController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Jobs\SendSMS;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class JobController extends Controller
{

    public function sendSMS()
    {
        $users = User::all(); 
        foreach ($users as $user) 
        {
            $job = (new SendSMS($user->mobile))->onQueue('sms');

            $this->dispatch($job);
            echo $player->mobile;
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

And I ran the queue using the command line,

now I have two problems

first : the request is very slow, meaning I wait around 20 seconds for the http request to be done to go for the next user, can I send the request and go to the second user without waiting for the response from the sms api ?

second : can I run the dispatch without actually running the method in the controller, like I want the jobs to be queued using command line for example or any other approach.

Comment: Look at this: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#async-requests

Comment: tried to do async requests, its much faster but even when its finished it didnt reach to the users

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a job for each user mobile, create a `SendSMSToAllUsers` job and your request will be very quick. The `SendSMSToAllUsers` job will fetch all users an dispatch a new job for each user.

To dispatch without actually running the method in the controller you only need to include the `Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs` trait in any of your classes (artisan commands, queue Jobs, etc...) and use `$this->dispatch($job)` method.

For better performance either use the async features of Guzzle or dispatch your SMS jobs to multiple queues and run in parallel several queue workers, one for each queue using the parameter `--queue=myqueue`. Having 25k users is a enough reason for using multiple queues.

For instance, you can create 10 queues: 'sms-0' for phone numbers ending in 0, 'sms-1' for phone numbers ending in 1, ... and so on. Or you can create two queues, 'sms-odd' and 'sms-even' for odd or even numbers.

Comment: How I will dispatch the job for each user inside the handle ?

Comment: Exactly the same way you are already using in your controller: `$this->dispatch($job)`. Just remember to include the `Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs` trait