# Add a Delay for Sending SMS to User Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my project, i want to send a reward SMS to user after winning a specified game.
So I have implemented the code in the `GameController` like below..

```
//some data
$this->send($mobile_number, $message);
//some data
```

The Send Function is defined as a `Trait` like below

```
public function send($mobile_number, $message)
{
    $username = config('app.filee')['username'];
    $password = config('app.file')['password'];
    $sender_id = config('app.file')['sender_id'];


    $url = "URL...username=" . $username . "&password=" . $password . "&from=" . $sender_id . "&to=" . $mobile_number . "&content=" . urlencode($message);

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    \Log::info(['SMS_RESPONSE' => $response, 'SENT_MESSAGE' => $message]);
    return;
}
```

How Can I delay this send SMS to 5 min?

without changing many changes in the function?

Comment: Use Laravel Queues and set delay on it. More information [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching).

Comment: @Peppermintology sorry I am new to laravel.. do i need to add a job class ?and if I need then where should I write the send ()?.. can you tell me the work flow..?

Comment: Rather than my just posting magical code, I'd recommend taking a look at some online tutorials such as [this one which is quite quick](https://www.larashout.com/laravel-queues-step-by-step-guide) or [this one which goes in to more depth](https://www.larashout.com/laravel-queues-step-by-step-guide)

Answer (score 1):

Create a job that is responsible for sending messages via sms (put the sending logic in that file or another file and call it from there)

then queue this job to be sent after the delay that you want.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303005/send-multiple-sms-to-users-using-jobs) question can help to create the classes.
[This](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching) will can help you add a delay

Adapt this answer to your needs, it can be a good exercise. good luck

Comment: can we use a call back function without using jobclass  with dispatch and add delay to this?
`dispatch(function () use ($mobile_number,$message) {
                             $this->send($mobile_number, $message);
                        })->delay(now()->addMinutes(1));`

Comment: I dont think that it is possible (dont actually know, must search about it).
however its better to use the job class cause it wont delay the response that is going to be sent back while the sms is actually being sent.